# Does the 'S' in SQL stand for "standard" or "structured"?

Tags: sql

I'm thinking "structured", but my dad claims that when he taught a class that involved SQL (decades ago), they used "standard".  I was wondering if this changed over time, or is he mistaken?  I googled it with "standard" and did see some pages that said that's what it stands for.  Any old timers willing to give a history lesson?

Comment: I've heard it used as Simple, Structured, and Standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) says first:

> SQL often referred to as **Structured** Query Language.

And then further down:

> SQL was developed at IBM by Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce in the early 1970s. This version, initially called SEQUEL (**Structured** English Query Language).

There's no mention of "standard query language" on the whole page.

The other test of course is to search Google for "structured query language" vs "standard query language". For which I currently get 913,000 results compared to 124,000. So clearly "structured" wins, however interestingly there was apparently a divided preference at one time. This [site](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/sql.htm) says:

> In the early days of the system there was divided preference between Standard Query Language and Structured Query Language but it did not make a whole lot of difference since most people most of the time called it by the acronym SQL. Now the overwhelming but not complete preference is for Structured Query Language.

Comment: yeah wikipedia was the first place i checked, i just trust this site a little more ;) thank you!

Comment: @marty - Many answers here quote and use wikipedia as a resource.

Comment: yeah all the answers on this question do, just thought maybe someone else would have remembered first hand from back in the day.  wiki remains king i suppose.

Answer (score 6):

It stands for `Structured`.

The precursor was called `SEQUEL`, standing for `Structured English QUEry Language`.

From wikipedia:

> The acronym SEQUEL was later changed to SQL because "SEQUEL" was a trademark

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of Oracle Databases, for instance, it was called 'Standard Query Language'.  Yes, it is a structured language...but it is known to us old schoolers has ***Standard Query Language*** (SQL).

Now if you want to call it Structure that is entirely up to you.  Maybe we should use sSQL or lower case sql has the acronym instead of SQL in upper caps. Either way its entirely up to you. There is always someone trying to put a different twist on things.  Whatever acronym you use get the sequel script right.

Answer (score 0):

The original wasn't even SQL acronym, it was SEQUEL:  (from wiki)

> SQL was developed at IBM by Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce in the early 1970s. This version, initially called SEQUEL (Structured English Query Language), was designed to manipulate and retrieve data stored in IBM's original quasi-relational database management system, System R, which a group at IBM San Jose Research Laboratory had developed during the 1970s.[8] The acronym SEQUEL was later changed to SQL because "SEQUEL" was a trademark of the UK-based Hawker Siddeley aircraft company

Comment: Probably because your answer would be better off just as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly "structured" e.g. although logically the `SELECT` clause is evaluted after the `FROM` clause you cannot write a SQL statement that way because you would be violating its "structure".

Answer (score 0):

It is Structured Query Language but what i think is one of the reason why they thought it was "Standard Query language" is because SQL is ANSI and ISO which also at the i first place i also thought it was Standard Query Language which gets me wrong in exam.